# Outlook 2003 pops up error dialog with "Script Error", "Line 29", "Position 129" and no useful info

Tags: crash, microsoft-outlook-2003, vbscript

So I sit at my computer working on something in a totally different program, and spontaneously a dialog box appears with the title "Script Error" and message text:

```
Script Error

Line 29
Position 129

if x = "" then x = "GetRegValue(2, "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\" & pcode, "Displa<script language="VBScript">
```

All of the above is [sic]--it really says "Displa" and then starts a tag, and repeats "Script Error".

When I click "OK" the dialog and Outlook 2003 both close.

What the heck? What would cause something like that? Does Outlook even excecute VBScript?

Comment: Have VBA scripts in Tool>Macro>Macros? Any add-ins installed?

Comment: Tools >> Macro >> Macros is empty. I have the Live Meeting addin installed. Thanks.